# Outbound traffic with two interfaces for load balancing

Tags: networking, load-balancing, rsync

We have two interfaces on one server that serves icecast streams with the following configuration:

rfitz@streamer:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.9
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.7.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.7.0
    gateway 192.168.7.1
```

This results in this route table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use 
Iface
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.7.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

We use rsync to transfer files to another server and these outbound connections are stalling a lot now and not completing transfer. If I remove the gateway from eth1, then rsync no longer stalls, but then inbound traffic does not reach the server, not responding. After removing the eth1 gateway, I tried adding a static route as follows:

```
route add -net 192.168.7.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.7.1

rfitz@streamer:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.7.0     192.168.7.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth1
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

But this didn't help with allowing inbound traffic on eth1. Can someone suggest how this needs to be configured, how to get rsync not to stall with two gateways or allow the inbound traffic if only using one gateway?

All was working fine until we dropped eth1 temporarily while that router was out of service. I did back up the interfaces file and it was using two gateways and we did not have any problem with outbound rsync, something else must have gone wrong in the process as we brought the eth1 gateway back online and restored the interfaces file.

Answer (score 0):

In your first setup with 2 default gateways, only the first one is used (`192.168.7.1`): there can only be one active default gateway per routing table.

If you want to use 2 default gateways, you will need to create 2 different routing tables and use policy based routing to define when to use each of those routing tables.